# Display the first or second data in table using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I have scope.candidates variable in controller and display the data in my view form using ng-repeat. My problem is all the objects is displayed inside the table which should not. How can I display the vicePresidents object only in the table? Below is my code.

controller.js

```
$scope.alertMe = function (candidateGroup) {
alert(candidateGroup);
};

 $scope.candidates = {
  presidents : [
    {
      no:1,
      name:'Brooke Jovi Jon',
      votes:51,
    },
    {
      no:2,
      name:'Cabug-os Jerry',
      votes:23
    },
    {
      no:3,
      name:'Hoorane Nialle',
      votes:25
    }
  ],
  vicePresidents : [
    {
      no:11,
      name: 'Frank Joemar Timbang',
      votes:20
    },
    {
      no:12,
      name: 'Curtis Zaymond',
      votes:19
    },
    {
      no:13,
      name: 'Reeves Manny',
      votes:21
    }
  ]
};
```

view.html

```
<tbody ng-repeat="candidateGroup in candidates">
<tr ng-repeat="candidate in candidateGroup">
    <td>{{candidate.no}} {{candidate.name}}</td>
    <td><button ng-click="alertMe($parent.$index)">Alert me!</button></td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want the index of `vicePresidents` you must use ng-repeat like this:

```
 <table ng-repeat="item in candidates track by $index" ng-if="$index != 0">
    <tr ng-repeat="candidate in candidates.vicePresidents">
        <td>{{candidate.no}} {{candidate.name}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="alertMe($parent.$index)">Alert me!</button></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now the alert is workig!
because your $parent is the scope created by `ng-repeat="item in candidates track by $index"`

**EDIT**

To doing it more dynamically here is the updated code:

```
<table ng-repeat="item in candidates track by $index" ng-if="item == candidates.presidents">
    <tr ng-repeat="candidate in candidates.presidents">
        <td>{{candidate.no}} {{candidate.name}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="alertMe($parent.$index)">Alert me!</button></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm just changed the ng-if condition.

Her is updated plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/5yWccQXCO1Fol6PBseuD?p=preview

Comment: Hello I have another question. When I change the vicePresidents to presidents the alert is still the same. It's alert 1 again it should be 0 right? why is this happen?

Comment: Use http://plnkr.co/edit/5yWccQXCO1Fol6PBseuD?p=preview   you just need to cahnge your object (vicePresidents or presidents) in ng-repeat **and** in `ng-if ` (I change it)

Comment: @cheziHoyzer there must be some solution that will check the parent index, rather than doing it mannualy everytime.

Comment: Thankyou @cheziHoyzer that is a good answer. But I agree with Ved. Is there some possible solutions to get the index without manually doing it?

Comment: @Ved I agree with you. But it's too tricky. Do you have some ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this.I guess you only want to display vicePresidents data.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="candidateGroup in candidates.vicePresidents">
<tr ng-repeat="candidate in candidateGroup">
    <td>{{candidate.no}} {{candidate.name}}</td>
    <td><button ng-click="alertMe($parent.$index)">Alert me!</button></td> 
</tr>
```

OR,

```
<tbody ng-repeat="candidateGroup.vicePresidents in candidates">
<tr ng-repeat="candidate in candidateGroup">
    <td>{{candidateGroup.vicePresidents.no}} {{candidateGroup.vicePresidents.name}}</td>
    <td><button ng-click="alertMe($parent.$index)">Alert me!</button></td> 
</tr>
```